# Show posts ordered by category name

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, categories

I need to order the categories by name and then show the posts for each one.

I don't know what is wrong, tried everything. Any help?

```
<?php $categories = get_categories( array ('orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'asc' ) );?>

   <?php foreach ( $categories as $category );?>

       <?php if( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

               //CODE TO SHOW IS CORRECT

       <?php endwhile; else : ?>
       <?php endif; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

EDIT: Correct code to show posts ordered by category name asc.

```
<?php $categories = get_categories( array ('orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'asc' ) );?>
        
<?php $i=0;?>

<?php foreach ($categories as $category):?>

    <?php $category_id = $categories[$i]->cat_ID;?>
    
    <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => $category_id )); ?>

    <?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    //YOUR HTML

    <?php endwhile; else : ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php $i++;?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? e.g. Are you not getting any categories, are they not in the right order, are you getting an error? We can't help fix a problem when we don't know what it is! Also, I presume `get_gategories` is a typo in your question and not your real code?

Comment: Wordpress it's not able to compile that page. `get_categories` is a wordpress function.

Comment: `get_categories` is a WP function... `get_gategories` isn't.

Comment: That's true, but even using the right function it gives a critic error.

Comment: Well then, you need to tell us that information and the specific details of the error! As I said in my first comment - *we can't help you fix an error when we don't know what it is*! Please see [ask] to see what information you need to give us so that we are able to help you.

Comment: Sorry not being specific, but wp it's not giving much more information but "critic error". I do not know if there's a way to see the specific error in a wordpress error page.

Comment: So the page is completely blank except for the 2 words "critic error"? Nothing else? I've never seen that exact message before. Without more information, we really can't help you because we don't know what is going wrong! See how to [turn on debugging messages in WP](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) and let us know if you get more detailed info. Also try to debug your code to see which line is causing the problem - comment out the block of code and then add it back bit-by-bit until you work out which part it is.

Comment: You are completely right, thanks for the debbugging link, fixed it myself. I'll have all this things in mind for next questions.